# How to connect multiple rasspberry pi over a wifi network and make them communicate with each other?

Tags: raspi-config

i am a newbie to raspberry pi and i want to connect around 8 raspberry pi  in a local wi-fi network so that they work together. i am sorry if this is a very common question. thank you

Comment: if they all connect to the same access point, then, by the power of networking, they will all be able to communicate with each other in any networking protocol you decide to use to make them "work together"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please explain a bit more about making the Pis "work together."  In particular, please tell us your ultimate goal.  The answer given, make one of them an access point, will enable communication among them.  So will connecting them all to some other access point.  If they're all going to work on a single problem, you will likely need some software, too.  Exactly *what* software depends upon the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make one of your RasPis an access point. You will find many tutorials about this on the web, for example [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) or another way with [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a Wireless Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md). Then all other RasPis can connect to the access point and communicate to each other. From a default image the RasPis are able to do this out of the box.